# Multiple GeoJSON Feature Collections to a Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

Edit: The end objective is to monitor the movement of severe weather, determine its vector and make a prediction.

I'm working with a `GeoJSON` `FeatureCollection` from the National Severe Storms Laboratory.  The dataset is publicly available [here](https://mrms.ncep.noaa.gov/data/ProbSevere/PROBSEVERE/).

Here is a portion of a single `JSON` file.

```json
{"source": "NOAA/NCEP Central Operations",
 "product": "ProbSevere",
 "validTime": "20211011_010058 UTC",
 "productionTime": "20211011_010201 UTC",
 "machine": "vm-cprk-mrms-ops-probsvr1.ncep.noaa.gov",
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
     {"type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [[[-95.53, 38.92], [-95.50, 38.92], [-95.47, 38.90], [-95.47, 38.85], [-95.49, 38.83], [-95.49, 38.81], [-95.46, 38.78], [-95.37, 38.75], [-95.36, 38.74], [-95.36, 38.70], [-95.37, 38.69], [-95.39, 38.69], [-95.40, 38.68], [-95.46, 38.68], [-95.47, 38.67], [-95.51, 38.67], [-95.52, 38.66], [-95.56, 38.66], [-95.57, 38.67], [-95.59, 38.67], [-95.60, 38.68], [-95.68, 38.70], [-95.71, 38.73], [-95.71, 38.75], [-95.69, 38.78], [-95.60, 38.79], [-95.58, 38.81], [-95.58, 38.89], [-95.57, 38.89], [-95.53, 38.92]]]
      },
         "models": {
          "probsevere": {
              "PROB": "1",
              "LINE01": "ProbHail: 1%; ProbWind: 1%; ProbTor: 0%",
              "LINE02": "- MESH: 0.07 in.",
              "LINE03": "- VIL Density: 1.26 g/m^3",
              "LINE04": "- Flash Rate: 1 fl/min",
              "LINE05": "- Flash Density (max in last 30 min): 0.07 fl/min/km^2",
              "LINE06": "- Max LLAzShear: 0.003 /s",
              "LINE07": "- 98% LLAzShear: 0.002 /s",
              "LINE08": "- 98% MLAzShear: 0.003 /s",
              "LINE09": "- Norm. vert. growth rate: 2356Z 0.7%/min (weak)",
              "LINE10": "- EBShear: 45.9 kts; SRH 0-1km AGL: 93 m^2/s^2",
              "LINE11": "- MUCAPE: 440 J/kg; MLCAPE: 0 J/kg; MLCIN: 0 J/kg",
              "LINE12": "- MeanWind 1-3kmAGL: 15.6 kts",
              "LINE13": "- Wetbulb 0C hgt: 11.9 kft AGL",
              "LINE14": "- CAPE -10C to -30C: 123 J/kg; PWAT: 1.5 in.",
              "LINE15": "Avg. beam height (ARL): 2.96 kft / 0.90 km"
          },
          "probtor": {
              "PROB": "0",
              "LINE01": "ProbTor: 0%",
              "LINE02": "- Max LLAzShear: 0.003 /s (weak)",
              "LINE03": "- 98% LLAzShear: 0.002 /s (weak)",
              "LINE04": "- 98% MLAzShear: 0.003 /s (weak)",
              "LINE05": "- Flash Density: 0.07 fl/min/km^2",
              "LINE06": "- SRH 0-1km AGL: 93 m2/s2",
              "LINE07": "- EBShear: 45.9 kts",
              "LINE08": "- MeanWind 1-3kmAGL: 15.6 kts",
              "LINE09": "- MLCAPE/MLCIN: 0/0 J/kg",
              "LINE10": "Avg. beam height (ARL): 2.96 kft / 0.90 km"
          },
          "probhail": {
              "PROB": "1",
              "LINE01": "ProbHail: 1%",
              "LINE02": "- MESH: 0.07 in.",
              "LINE03": "- Flash Rate: 1 fl/min",
              "LINE04": "- Norm. vert. growth rate: 2356Z 0.7%/min (weak)",
              "LINE05": "- EBShear: 45.9 kts",
              "LINE06": "- CAPE -10C to -30C: 123 J/kg",
              "LINE07": "- PWAT: 1.5 in.",
              "LINE08": "- Wetbulb 0C hgt: 11.9 kft AGL"
          },
          "probwind": {
              "PROB": "1",
              "LINE01": "ProbWind: 1%",
              "LINE02": "- MESH: 0.07 in.",
              "LINE03": "- VIL Density: 1.26 g/m^3",
              "LINE04": "- Flash Rate: 1 fl/min",
              "LINE05": "- 98% LLAzShear: 0.002 /s (weak)",
              "LINE06": "- 98% MLAzShear: 0.003 /s (weak)",
              "LINE07": "- Norm. vert. growth rate: 2356Z 0.7%/min (weak)",
              "LINE08": "- EBShear: 45.9 kts",
              "LINE09": "- MeanWind 1-3kmAGL: 15.6 kts",
              "LINE10": "- MUCAPE: 440 J/kg; MLCAPE: 0 J/kg"
          }
      },
      "properties": {
          "MUCAPE": "440",
          "MLCAPE": "0",
          "MLCIN": "0",
          "EBSHEAR": "45.9",
          "SRH01KM": "93",
          "MEANWIND_1-3kmAGL": "15.6",
          "MESH": "0.07",
          "VIL_DENSITY": "1.26",
          "FLASH_RATE": "1",
          "FLASH_DENSITY": "0.07",
          "MAXLLAZ": "0.003",
          "P98LLAZ": "0.002",
          "P98MLAZ": "0.003",
          "MAXRC_EMISS": "2356Z 0.7%/min (weak)",
          "MAXRC_ICECF": "2251Z 0.0/min (weak)",
          "WETBULB_0C_HGT": "11.9",
          "PWAT": "1.5",
          "CAPE_M10M30": "123",
          "LJA": "0.0",
          "SIZE": "518",
          "AVG_BEAM_HGT": "2.96 kft / 0.90 km",
          "MOTION_EAST": "8.691",
          "MOTION_SOUTH": "-10.096",
          "PS": "5",
          "ID": "89234"
      }},
     {"type": "Feature",
         "geometry": {
             "type": "Polygon",
             "coordinates": [[[-96.73, 37.22], [-96.71, 37.22], [-96.69, 37.20], [-96.66, 37.19], [-96.63, 37.16], [-96.61, 37.16], [-96.60, 37.15], [-96.60, 37.11], [-96.57, 37.08], [-96.55, 37.08], [-96.54, 37.07], [-96.48, 37.07], [-96.46, 37.04], [-96.46, 37.01], [-96.50, 36.93], [-96.51, 36.93], [-96.54, 36.90], [-96.56, 36.90], [-96.57, 36.88], [-96.58, 36.88], [-96.62, 36.84], [-96.64, 36.84], [-96.65, 36.83], [-96.71, 36.83], [-96.72, 36.84], [-96.74, 36.84], [-96.74, 36.86], [-96.72, 36.88], [-96.72, 36.90], [-96.70, 36.92], [-96.66, 36.92], [-96.64, 36.94], [-96.64, 37.01], [-96.65, 37.02], [-96.65, 37.06], [-96.66, 37.07], [-96.68, 37.07], [-96.71, 37.03], [-96.75, 37.03], [-96.77, 37.05], [-96.77, 37.08], [-96.76, 37.09], [-96.76, 37.12], [-96.75, 37.13], [-96.75, 37.20], [-96.73, 37.22]]]
         },
      "models": {
             "probsevere": {
                 "PROB": "3",
                 "LINE01": "ProbHail: 1%; ProbWind: 3%; ProbTor: 0%",
                 "LINE02": "- MESH: 0.35 in.",
                 "LINE03": "- VIL Density: 1.96 g/m^3",
                 "LINE04": "- Flash Rate: 16 fl/min",
                 "LINE05": "- Flash Density (max in last 30 min): 0.51 fl/min/km^2",
                 "LINE06": "- Max LLAzShear: 0.003 /s",
                 "LINE07": "- 98% LLAzShear: 0.002 /s",
                 "LINE08": "- 98% MLAzShear: 0.003 /s",
                 "LINE09": "- Norm. vert. growth rate: N/A",
                 "LINE10": "- EBShear: 51.9 kts; SRH 0-1km AGL: 173 m^2/s^2",
                 "LINE11": "- MUCAPE: 1574 J/kg; MLCAPE: 1103 J/kg; MLCIN: -19 J/kg",
                 "LINE12": "- MeanWind 1-3kmAGL: 19.6 kts",
                 "LINE13": "- Wetbulb 0C hgt: 11.8 kft AGL",
                 "LINE14": "- CAPE -10C to -30C: 353 J/kg; PWAT: 1.8 in.",
                 "LINE15": "Avg. beam height (ARL): 5.04 kft / 1.54 km"
             },
             "probtor": {
                 "PROB": "0",
                 "LINE01": "ProbTor: 0%",
                 "LINE02": "- Max LLAzShear: 0.003 /s (weak)",
                 "LINE03": "- 98% LLAzShear: 0.002 /s (weak)",
                 "LINE04": "- 98% MLAzShear: 0.003 /s (weak)",
                 "LINE05": "- Flash Density: 0.51 fl/min/km^2",
                 "LINE06": "- SRH 0-1km AGL: 173 m2/s2",
                 "LINE07": "- EBShear: 51.9 kts",
                 "LINE08": "- MeanWind 1-3kmAGL: 19.6 kts",
                 "LINE09": "- MLCAPE/MLCIN: 1103/-19 J/kg",
                 "LINE10": "Avg. beam height (ARL): 5.04 kft / 1.54 km"
             },
             "probhail": {
                 "PROB": "1",
                 "LINE01": "ProbHail: 1%",
                 "LINE02": "- MESH: 0.35 in.",
                 "LINE03": "- Flash Rate: 16 fl/min",
                 "LINE04": "- Norm. vert. growth rate: N/A",
                 "LINE05": "- EBShear: 51.9 kts",
                 "LINE06": "- CAPE -10C to -30C: 353 J/kg",
                 "LINE07": "- PWAT: 1.8 in.",
                 "LINE08": "- Wetbulb 0C hgt: 11.8 kft AGL"
             },
             "probwind": {
                 "PROB": "3",
                 "LINE01": "ProbWind: 3%",
                 "LINE02": "- MESH: 0.35 in.",
                 "LINE03": "- VIL Density: 1.96 g/m^3",
                 "LINE04": "- Flash Rate: 16 fl/min",
                 "LINE05": "- 98% LLAzShear: 0.002 /s (weak)",
                 "LINE06": "- 98% MLAzShear: 0.003 /s (weak)",
                 "LINE07": "- Norm. vert. growth rate: N/A",
                 "LINE08": "- EBShear: 51.9 kts",
                 "LINE09": "- MeanWind 1-3kmAGL: 19.6 kts",
                 "LINE10": "- MUCAPE: 1574 J/kg; MLCAPE: 1103 J/kg"
             }
         }
      }
 ]}
```

For now I am most interested in...

```py
collection['validTime']
feat['geometry']['coordinates']
feat['property']['ID']
feat['models']['probsevere'&'probtor'&'probwind'&'probhail']['PROB']
```

Here's what I got.

```py
IDX = pd.IndexSlice


def load_samples(path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    with open(path) as feat:
        collection = json.load(feat)
    features = collection.pop('features')

    def make_parameters(feat: Dict[str, Any]) -> pd.Series:
        # index model probs
        probabilities = (
            pd.DataFrame(feat['models']).loc['PROB']).astype(int)
        # insert coordinates
        probabilities['coordinates'] = feat['geometry']['coordinates']

        return probabilities

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        # index by id
        feat['properties']['ID']: make_parameters(feat)
        # itterate features
        for feat in features
    }, orient='index')

    # insert validTIme
    dataframe['validTime'] = (
        pd.to_datetime(collection['validTime'], format="%Y%m%d_%H%M%S UTC"))

    return (
        dataframe
        # index validtime
        .set_index(['validTime'], append=True, drop=True)
        # stack columns
        .stack()
        # move validtime to column
        .unstack(1)
        # give index names
        .rename_axis(['ID', 'parameter'])
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    paths = glob(os.path.join('sample_data/', '*.json'))

    samps = pd.concat([load_samples(path) for path in paths], axis=1)

    samps = samps.reindex(sorted(samps.columns), axis=1)

    print(samps)
```

OUT:

```
validTime                                        2021-10-11 00:00:53                                2021-10-11 00:02:40  ...                                2021-10-11 00:58:56                                2021-10-11 01:00:58
ID    parameter                                                                                                          ...                                                                                                      
89234 coordinates  [[[-96.06, 38.4], [-95.99, 38.4], [-95.97, 38....  [[[-96.03, 38.41], [-95.98, 38.41], [-95.96, 3...  ...  [[[-95.55, 38.91], [-95.51, 38.91], [-95.48, 3...  [[[-95.53, 38.92], [-95.5, 38.92], [-95.47, 38...
      probhail                                                     1                                                  1  ...                                                  1                                                  1
      probsevere                                                   1                                                  1  ...                                                  1                                                  1
      probtor                                                      0                                                  0  ...                                                  0                                                  0
      probwind                                                     1                                                  1  ...                                                  1                                                  1
...                                                              ...                                                ...  ...                                                ...                                                ...
90393 coordinates                                                NaN                                                NaN  ...                                                NaN  [[[-99.35, 31.38], [-99.31, 31.38], [-99.3, 31...
      probhail                                                   NaN                                                NaN  ...                                                NaN                                                  8
      probsevere                                                 NaN                                                NaN  ...                                                NaN                                                 10
      probtor                                                    NaN                                                NaN  ...                                                NaN                                                  1
      probwind                                                   NaN                                                NaN  ...                                                NaN                                                 10

[1880 rows x 31 columns]
```

USAGE:

```py
print(samps.loc[IDX['89234', 'coordinates'], :])
```

OUT:

```
validTime
2021-10-11 00:00:53    [[[-96.06, 38.4], [-95.99, 38.4], [-95.97, 38....
2021-10-11 00:02:40    [[[-96.03, 38.41], [-95.98, 38.41], [-95.96, 3...
2021-10-11 00:04:47    [[[-96.0, 38.43], [-95.94, 38.43], [-95.93, 38...
2021-10-11 00:06:55    [[[-95.96, 38.45], [-95.92, 38.43], [-95.9, 38...
2021-10-11 00:08:38    [[[-95.98, 38.46], [-95.93, 38.46], [-95.9, 38...
2021-10-11 00:10:59    [[[-95.95, 38.48], [-95.91, 38.48], [-95.9, 38...
2021-10-11 00:12:40    [[[-95.96, 38.48], [-95.91, 38.48], [-95.88, 3...
2021-10-11 00:14:44    [[[-95.93, 38.5], [-95.88, 38.5], [-95.86, 38....
2021-10-11 00:16:50    [[[-95.89, 38.53], [-95.86, 38.52], [-95.82, 3...
2021-10-11 00:18:39    [[[-95.89, 38.53], [-95.87, 38.53], [-95.83, 3...
2021-10-11 00:20:48    [[[-95.87, 38.55], [-95.85, 38.55], [-95.81, 3...
2021-10-11 00:22:57    [[[-95.86, 38.56], [-95.82, 38.56], [-95.79, 3...
2021-10-11 00:24:40    [[[-95.85, 38.58], [-95.8, 38.58], [-95.77, 38...
2021-10-11 00:26:58    [[[-95.84, 38.59], [-95.78, 38.59], [-95.75, 3...
2021-10-11 00:28:52    [[[-95.81, 38.61], [-95.77, 38.61], [-95.76, 3...
2021-10-11 00:30:43    [[[-95.81, 38.63], [-95.76, 38.62], [-95.64, 3...
2021-10-11 00:32:56    [[[-95.81, 38.64], [-95.77, 38.64], [-95.75, 3...
2021-10-11 00:34:59    [[[-95.81, 38.64], [-95.75, 38.64], [-95.7, 38...
2021-10-11 00:36:41    [[[-95.77, 38.67], [-95.73, 38.66], [-95.68, 3...
2021-10-11 00:38:44    [[[-95.78, 38.67], [-95.74, 38.67], [-95.67, 3...
2021-10-11 00:40:52    [[[-95.77, 38.67], [-95.73, 38.67], [-95.72, 3...
2021-10-11 00:42:42    [[[-95.77, 38.67], [-95.71, 38.67], [-95.7, 38...
2021-10-11 00:44:53    [[[-95.7, 38.68], [-95.67, 38.68], [-95.66, 38...
2021-10-11 00:46:51    [[[-95.68, 38.7], [-95.63, 38.7], [-95.62, 38....
2021-10-11 00:48:54    [[[-95.68, 38.71], [-95.58, 38.71], [-95.54, 3...
2021-10-11 00:50:59    [[[-95.59, 38.84], [-95.54, 38.84], [-95.53, 3...
2021-10-11 00:52:59    [[[-95.57, 38.87], [-95.54, 38.87], [-95.51, 3...
2021-10-11 00:54:52    [[[-95.56, 38.89], [-95.51, 38.89], [-95.5, 38...
2021-10-11 00:56:52    [[[-95.56, 38.89], [-95.5, 38.89], [-95.49, 38...
2021-10-11 00:58:56    [[[-95.55, 38.91], [-95.51, 38.91], [-95.48, 3...
2021-10-11 01:00:58    [[[-95.53, 38.92], [-95.5, 38.92], [-95.47, 38...
Name: (89234, coordinates), dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `IDX` seems unused, so you can delete that.

You've done a good job in adding initial typehints.

Your data have a normalisation problem: there is a significant cardinality mismatch between your coordinates and their model. The sanest way to fix this is to return two separate dataframes that use the same indices, one dedicated to probabilities and the other coordinates. The coordinate dataframe will unpack the nested lists and have simple `x` and `y` columns.

I disagree with the choice of stacking. The probability titles are not well-represented as index levels and should just be columns.

Your datetime format should not hard-code UTC, and should instead [use %Z](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

### Suggested

```
import json
from typing import Any, Iterator

import pandas as pd


def load_samples(path: str) -> tuple[
    pd.DataFrame,  # probability dataframe
    pd.DataFrame,  # coordinate dataframe
]:
    with open(path) as feat:
        collection = json.load(feat)
    features: list[dict[str, Any]] = collection['features']

    def make_probs() -> Iterator[dict[str, Any]]:
        for feat in features:
            probs = {
                model_name: int(model['PROB'])
                for model_name, model in feat['models'].items()
            }
            yield {
                'ID': feat['properties']['ID'],
                **probs,
            }

    def make_coords() -> Iterator[dict[str, Any]]:
        for feat in features:
            coords, = feat['geometry']['coordinates']
            for x, y in coords:
                yield {
                    'ID': feat['properties']['ID'],
                    'x': x, 'y': y,
                }

    prob_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tuple(make_probs()), index='ID')
    coord_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tuple(make_coords()), index='ID')

    dt = pd.Series(
        name='validTime',
        data=pd.to_datetime(collection['validTime'], format='%Y%m%d_%H%M%S %Z'),
    )

    prob_df.set_index(dt.repeat(len(prob_df)), append=True, inplace=True)
    coord_df.set_index(dt.repeat(len(coord_df)), append=True, inplace=True)

    return prob_df, coord_df


def main() -> None:
    prob_df, coord_df = load_samples('MRMS_PROBSEVERE_20220209_164430.json')

    print(prob_df)
    print(coord_df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

```
                                 probsevere  probtor  probhail  probwind
ID    validTime                                                         
57216 2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00           2        0         2         1
57240 2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00           1        0         0         1
57247 2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00           2        0         0         2
57255 2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00           1        0         0         1
57256 2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00           1        0         0         1
57258 2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00           1        0         0         1
                                     x      y
ID    validTime                              
57216 2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00 -79.38  26.36
      2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00 -79.34  26.34
      2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00 -79.33  26.32
      2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00 -79.34  26.29
      2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00 -79.36  26.28
...                                ...    ...
57258 2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00 -86.20  30.33
      2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00 -86.11  30.33
      2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00 -86.11  30.25
      2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00 -86.20  30.25
      2022-02-09 16:44:30+00:00 -86.20  30.33

[94 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I learn a lot from your suggestions. One thing to to in your suggestion is with the x,y. The coordinates are not a point, it’s a polygon.

Comment: That's fine, and I didn't constrain the suggestion to points only. I assumed it was a polygon, and this new representation will deal with polygons more easily than the original: all of the vertices in one polygon can be grouped by a set of shared index values.

Comment: Oh I see it stacks x,y